# What is the difference between FAILURE_SAFETY and QUORUM_THRESHOLD?

Tags: consensus

My assumption is that `FAILURE_SAFETY` refers to how many nodes in **your** quorum slice you allow to fail while `QUORUM_THRESHOLD` refers to the percentage of nodes in an quorum that's necessary to come to a consensus?

So I if configure `3` validator nodes with `FAILURE_SAFETY=1` and `QUORUM_THRESHOLD=66`, that means if more than one of the `3` nodes fail I will fail while `QUORUM_THRESHOLD` may contain other nodes that are not part of my configuration?